# iPhone Calculator decimal digits reversed on input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, syntax

While doing tutorial work, it took me forever to implement a decimal point, and now i have one, that works in the formula, but the issue is it reverses the input - e.g.. enter 1.4, the calculator screen shows it as 4.1 - i know its something to do with my housekeeping of the variables.. planning to use BOOL's instead of a float..but..any takers?

The code:

```
     - (IBAction) pressedDecimal: (id) sender
     {
       pressedDec = 1;
     }

    - (IBAction) pressedDigit: (id) sender 
     {
       if (pressedDec == 1) 
       {currentNumber = .1 * currentNumber + (double)[sender tag];
       calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
      }
else

     {

       currentNumber =  currentNumber * 10 + (double)[sender tag];
       calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
       pressedDec = 0;

      }
     }



  - (IBAction) pressedOperation: (id) sender 
   {
if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
else {
    switch (currentOperation) {
        case 1:
            result = result + currentNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - currentNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * currentNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = result / currentNumber;
            break;
        case 5:
            currentOperation = 0;
            break;


    }

}
currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
currentOperation = [sender tag];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider more carefully what this extract from your code does:

```
currentNumber = .1 * currentNumber + (double)[sender tag];
```

(I'm not being very explicit because if I've understood the question right you're doing this in order to learn, and the more you have to think the better you'll learn :-).)

Comment: thank you so much, and you are exactly right.  As further illustrated by sch.  I only hope the next question i have gets answered in a similar format.  With a fledgling developer, sometimes just an extra set of eyes to say "hey!  what are you thinking right here" is what they need.  I appreciate your caring about my learning path immensely!

Comment: Glad to be of service! You should consider accepting either sch's answer or mine. Good luck with your learning...

Comment: Gareth...im having an issue.  i want to accept your answer a lot because it made me answer myself, but for future searching of other users i believe protocol would have me accept his as it displays an answer, and may save a duplicate question from being asked?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Anyone reading this question will find both answers anyway. I suggest you accept whichever answer you think is better; I promise I won't be offended if you choose sch's, and I bet sch won't be offended if you choose mine. (It's not as if either of us is desperately short of SO reputation points.)

Comment: Ah, I see you accepted sch's. As promised, I am not offended. :-)

Comment: Gareth... This is for you:                                  currentNumber = currentNumber + (double)[sender tag] * 0.1;              .. thats what took me HOURS after seeing sch's method did NOT work at all like it should, however, this method works perfect now.  i appreciate you making me think and suggest all news to do the same.

Comment: Careful! What happens if you enter 1.23? I think what you've just proposed will produce 1.5. I agree with sch that you would likely do better to keep hold of the whole string.

Comment: yup, your right Gareth, just as i celebrated and went to sleep, i woke up this morning and sandboxed it on my iPhone to play with it, and it does just as you stated.  Sch's method does not work either.  Please look at my other post, and Gareth...if you can straighten this out for me, i need to see it work, and then break down how it was done, as i am fried...see link here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369173/iphone-calculator-tutorial-help-decimal-style-again

Answer (score -1):

Lesson number 2 here: [Stanford iTunes U tutorial](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522) covers building a simple calculator. Might be helpful. Either way it's a great tutorial series.

Comment: i think that that is the tutorial he is doing, and it doesn't cover the decimal point, that is the homework.

Comment: downloading from iTunes now, I remember hearing about this a while ago, seeing it was made in 2010, i hope i can separate what Xcode 4+ does versus the version it was back then.  I thank you very much as this is exactly what i need..tutoring lol.